# Points in Right Margin not aligning when I change question label (Exam Class)

Tags: exam, points

I am trying to put brackets around my question label as follows: \renewcommand{\questionlabel}{(\thequestion)}

However, when I do this, the points in the right margin are not perfectly aligned as shown:[image]

However, when I remove the first bracket around the question label as follows:
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\thequestion)}, the alignment is not impacted. See below

[image]

Can someone please explain why the alignment changes when I add a bracket to the front of the question label. I really want to have the question labels as (a), (b) , etc. But this alignment issue is driving me insane.
Thanks

Comment: This question could benefit from adding a working code segment that will reproduce the stated results. As is it is a guess of code with use of the two segments given.